# refresh/update listview titanium

Tags: listview, titanium, refresh, updates

I have a program that has a listview when user clicks on item a details view opens, the user can edit in it and when the user presses on update button , the current window will be closed and the listview will be updated.

This is my code:

```
arr = [user1, user2, user3, user4];

var sections = [];

var DataSection = Ti.UI.createListSection({
    headerTitle : 'Data'
});
DataSection.setItems(MyDataSet);
sections.push(DataSection);

myListView.setSections(sections);
myListView.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e) {
    var myWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor : '#000'
    });
    var h_view = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : '#fff',
        layout : 'horizontal'
    });
    var userImg = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        image : arr[e.itemIndex].getimage(),
        width : 100,
        height : 100
    });
    var v_view = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : '#fff',
        layout : 'vertical'
    });
    var nameLabel = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        value : arr[e.itemIndex].getName(),
        color : '#000'
    });
    var mobileLabel = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        value : arr[e.itemIndex].getMob(),
        color : '#000'
    });
    var labelAge = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        value : arr[e.itemIndex].getage(),
        color : '#000'
    });
    var basicSwitch = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
        titleOn : 'Male',
        titleOff : 'Female'
    });
    basicSwitch.setValue(arr[e.itemIndex].getgender());
    var updateButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        text : 'update'
    });
    var index = e.itemIndex;
    updateButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        arr[index].username = nameLabel.value;
        arr[index].setAge(labelAge.value);
        arr[index].setMob(mobileLabel.value);
        arr[index].setGender(basicSwitch.value);
          // I want to update the listview here
        myWin.close();
    });

    h_view.add(userImg);
    v_view.add(nameLabel);
    v_view.add(labelAge);
    v_view.add(mobileLabel);
    v_view.add(basicSwitch);
    v_view.add(updateButton);
    h_view.add(v_view);
    myWin.add(h_view);

    myWin.open();
});
win1.add(myListView);
```

Edit:

I have tried to use

```
 Titanium.UI.createRefreshControl({});
```

but I always get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<UI> has no method 'createRefreshControl'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to : first get the item that you have to update, then update only this item ...

```
myListView.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e) {
     //get the item to be updated
     var user= e.section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
     //edit this user here
     user.name.text="Coyote";
     //then update the listview with the new data :
       e.section.updateItemAt(e.itemIndex, user); 
});
```